# Short form for Java If Else statement

Tags: java, if-statement, ternary-operator, short

I have a method which checks for nulls. Is there a way to reduce the number of lines in the method? Currently, the code looks "dirty":

```
private int similarityCount (String one, String two) {

    if (one == null && two == null) {
        return 1;
    } else if (one == null && two != null) {
        return 2;
    } else if (one != null && two == null) {
        return 3;
    } else {
        if(isMatch(one, two))
             return 4;
        return 5;
    }

}
```

Comment: Firstly, if  `return` value inside `if` block, you don't need to use `else`.

Comment: you can use ternary condition.

Comment: There is no performance difference using shorthand or if-else, it is better to write readable code and let ppl understand your code, the piece of code above is already clear and good enough.

Comment: You say you want to reduce the number of lines of code. The reason is the code smell of your example. Less lines won't fix that. Less complexity will.

Comment: Can you refactor isMatch to return 4 or 5 instead of a boolean? That would allow you to simplify the last else

Comment: **Disclaimer**: I'm not a Java guy. But I'm pretty sure every algol-descended language has `switch`...and on a side note what the hell is the point of a type system if your code still needs explicit null checks?

Comment: The answer is none of the above, and none of the below, and more as to why there is a specific need to do whole different things for `one` and `two`, mainly, why `similarityCount(one, two)` would be different than `similarityCount(two, one)` (the name doesn't imply that). This comes down to pure opinion.

Comment: You could also use a matrix to store the result.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

```
private int similarityCount (String one, String two) {

    if (one == null && two == null) {
        return 1;
    } 

    if (one == null) {
        return 2;
    } 

    if (two == null) {
        return 3;
    } 

    if (isMatch(one, two)) {
        return 4;
    }
    return 5;
}
```

Comment: You could even remove `&& two!=null` from the second `if` as it is invariably not `null` when that part of the code reaches execution. You could also use `assert` to assert the non-nullness of variables on certain execution paths (when `-ea`, anyway, which should be the default).

Comment: This is the more readable choice. The only thing that bugs my inner perfectionist about this solution is that you have to do the same null checks multiple times for cases 2 and 3. Then again, you can always address it later on if it turns out to be an issue.

Comment: Why the ternary for `isMatch(one, two)`? Why not just another if-statement? That would fit much better with the existing flow, and read more smoothly.

Comment: @CAD97 I actually like to use `assert` for code that will 100% always be true *even if `-ea` is not on* because it is sort of like a more informative comment at that point. I only use it for things that can only be true because you can't rely on `-ea` being on.

Comment: @CaptainMan that's how assert should be used, but there are cases when your assumption isn't true and the assert fails; this is why they run with `-ea`. In any case, if an assert fails your code _is_ going to misbehave so (at least in debug) I'd prefer a crash that tells me the wrong assumption.

Comment: I don't understand the logic behind the last line breaking format. It seems like the last line should be two lines: `if(isMatch(one,two) { return 4; } return 5;

Comment: Agree that the last line should be seperated into 2 conditions.

Answer (score 33):

I prefer nested conditions in such cases :

```
private int similarityCount (String one, String two) {
    if (one==null) {
        if (two==null) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 2;
        }
    } else {
        if (two==null) {
            return 3;
        } else {
            return isMatch(one, two) ? 4 : 5;
        }
    }
}
```

Of course you can achieve a shorter version by using more ternary conditional operators.

```
private int similarityCount (String one, String two) {  
    if (one==null) {
        return (two==null) ? 1 : 2;
    } else {
        return (two==null) ? 3 : isMatch(one, two) ? 4 : 5;
    }
}
```

Or even (now this is getting less readable) :

```
private int similarityCount (String one, String two) {  
    return (one==null) ? ((two==null) ? 1 : 2) : ((two==null) ? 3 : isMatch(one, two) ? 4 : 5);
}
```

Comment: Effort worth upvoting

Comment: I would prefer the second. The nested if-elses make the first one hard to take in at a glance, imo. It might be because of the distance between the last return and the conditions leading there.

Comment: I have to say I find this way of stating the logic quite convoluted. It tears apart the `null` checks into two general cases `one == null` and `one != null` when, in reality, we are *really* interested whether either `one` or `two` is `null`, or neither. As a consequence, I would recommend against all of the options presented here.

Comment: @KonradRudolph We have different return values for the 4 cases of both null, both not null, only one is null, only two is null, so I'm not sure why you are saying we are `really interested whether either one or two is null, or neither`.

Comment: @Eran Yeah, the return values slightly confound this but I submit that this is either a bad example or some questionable design to begin with. At any rate, `null`s should almost always be treated specially, apart from the actual logic. In fact, *not* doing so is in itself bad design because causes `null`s to proliferate, when the opposite should be the case.

Comment: You can get rid of the `else` in both of your first 2 examples. `if (one==null) { return foo; } return bar;` etc.

Answer (score 25):

Since the actual purpose of the function seems to be to handle non-`null` objects by matching them, I’d handle all the `null` checks in a guard statement at the beginning.

Then, once you’ve established that no argument is `null`, you can handle the actual logic:

```
private int similarityCount(String a, String b) {
    if (a == null || b == null) {
        return a == b ? 1 : a == null ? 2 : 3;
    }

    return isMatch(a, b) ? 4 : 5;
}
```

This is both more concise and more readable than the other options.

That said, *real* functions wouldn’t usually return such numeric codes. Unless your method was simplified to exemplify the problem, I’d strongly urge you to reconsider the logic and instead write something akin to what follows:

```
private boolean similarityCount(String a, String b) {
    if (a == null || b == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }

    return isMatch(a, b);
}
```

Or:

```
private boolean similarityCount(String a, String b) {
    if (a == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("a");
    }
    if (b == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("b");
    }

    return isMatch(a, b);
}
```

These approaches would be more conventional. On the flip side, they may trigger an exception. We can avoid this by returning a `java.util.Optional<Boolean>` in Java 8:

```
private Optional<Boolean> similarityCount(String a, String b) {
    if (a == null || b == null) {
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    return Optional.of(isMatch(a, b));
}
```

At first glance this may seem to be no better than returning `null` but [optionals are in fact far superior](http://www.deadcoderising.com/2015-10-06-java-8-removing-null-checks-with-optional/).

Comment: Great answer, always good to look at the solution as such before looking to improve the code.

Answer (score 9):

The code looks clear enough for me. You can make it shorter with nesting and ternary operators:

```
if(one==null) {
    return two==null ? 1 : 2;
}
if(two==null) {
    return 3;
} 
return isMatch(one,two) ? 4 : 5;
```

Comment: I am not sure if shorter code is better than more readable code.
I would left it with four `if` without `else` and `return 5;` at the end of block if no if is fullfiled

Comment: @RadekJ I agree that more readable version is preferable. One ternary operator on the line doesn't really reduce readability, though. And guard statements are easier to read in my opinion. Post your version, though, I'd upvote it :)

Comment: @RadekJ actually, Manh Le's answer is pretty close to your description.

Comment: Yep I agree, I would write something like Manh Le, but your code is good compromise :)

Answer (score 5):

It can be done in one line using Java conditional operator:

```
return (one==null?(two==null?1:2):(two==null?3:(isMatch(one,two)?4:5)));
```

Comment: Just because a thing *can* be done, does not mean it should :)

Comment: I thought the user was asking shorter way. :) So dont know why downvote.

Comment: @SachinSarawgi i upvote for you coz there is no reason to downvote anyway

Comment: Thanks @PSo for understanding the answer.

Comment: You answer is indeed not correct but the idea did pull out, nice one

Comment: This code is (still) not equivalent to the code in question.

Comment: @SachinSarawgi Nevermind :) No, it's not. Check out the last version in Eran's answer.

Answer (score 5):

You *can* create a pseudo-lookup-table. Some people frown on the nested ternary operators and it's highly dependent on whitespace for readability, but it *can* be a very readable approach to conditional returning:

```
private int similarityCount (String one, String two) {
    return (one == null && two == null) ? 1
         : (one == null && two != null) ? 2
         : (one != null && two == null) ? 3
         : isMatch(one, two)            ? 4
         :                                5;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I like expressions.

```
private static int similarityCount (String one, String two) {    
    return one == null ? 
        similarityCountByTwoOnly(two) : 
        two == null ? 3 : (isMatch(one, two) ? 4 : 5)
    ;
}

private static int similarityCountByTwoOnly(String two) {
    return two == null ? 1 : 2;
}
```

As an aside, I would probably challenge why you are doing this. I would assume you would do some kind of check on the returned integer after you've evaluated it and branch your logic based on it. If that is the case, you've just made a less readable check for null where the user of your method needs to understand the contract implicit in the value of the integer.

Also, here's a simple solution for when you need to check if strings are equal when they may be null:

```
boolean same = one == null ? two == null : one.equals(two);
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting rid of IF statements is good fun. Using a Map is one way of doing this. It doesn't fit this case exactly because of the call to isMatch, but I offer it as an alternative which cuts the similarityCount method body to a single line with one IF

The following code has two IFs. If GetOrDefault didn't evaluate the second argument, it could be reduced to one. Unfortunately it does so the null check inside isMatch is necessary.

You could go a lot further with this if you wanted to. For example, isMatch could return 4 or 5 rather than a boolean which would help you simplify further.

```
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.EqualsBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.HashCodeBuilder;

import java.util.Map;

public class SimilarityCount {

    private Map<SimilarityCountKey, Integer> rtn = ImmutableMap.of(new SimilarityCountKey(null, null), 1, new SimilarityCountKey(null, ""), 2, new SimilarityCountKey("", null), 3);

    public int similarityCount(String one, String two) {
        return rtn.getOrDefault(new SimilarityCountKey(one, two), isMatch(one, two) ? 4 : 5);
    }

    private boolean isMatch(String one, String two) {
        if (one == null || two == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return one.equals(two);
    }

    private class SimilarityCountKey {
        private final boolean one;
        private final boolean two;

        public SimilarityCountKey(String one, String two) {
            this.one = one == null;
            this.two = two == null;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            return EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(this, obj);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return HashCodeBuilder.reflectionHashCode(this);
        }
    }
}
```

In case anyone else fancies a crack at another solution, here are some tests to help you get started

```
 import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;

public class SimilarityCountTest {

    @Test
    public void one(){
        Assert.assertThat(new SimilarityCount().similarityCount(null,null), is(1));
    }

    @Test
    public void two(){
        Assert.assertThat(new SimilarityCount().similarityCount(null,""), is(2));
    }

    @Test
    public void three(){
        Assert.assertThat(new SimilarityCount().similarityCount("",null), is(3));
    }

    @Test
    public void four(){
        Assert.assertThat(new SimilarityCount().similarityCount("",""), is(4));
    }

    @Test
    public void five(){
        Assert.assertThat(new SimilarityCount().similarityCount("a","b"), is(5));
    }

}
```

Comment: Every line of code one writes is a liability. http://wiki.c2.com/?SoftwareAsLiability . In addition, KISS and YAGNI principles apply.

Comment: The cyclomatic complexity of this solution is considerably lower though - 2 ifs vs (at least) five depending on how isMatch is implemented. I agree it is not a neat solution for this case but for many if/switch statements this approach can reduce complexity dramatically.

Comment: I can't see how YAGNI applies though. All the code is in use as far as I can see

Comment: If I read your argument correctly you chose a map for the extensibility in future. The counter argument to that is YAGNI.

Answer (score 0):

This should be slightly faster if neither is null, as it only performs one 'if' statement in this case.

```
private int similarityCount (String one, String two) {

    if (one == null || two == null) {  // Something is null
        if (two != null) { // Only one is null
            return 2;
        }

        if (one != null) { // Only two is null
            return 3;
        }

        return 1; // Both must be null
    } 

    return isMatch(one, two) ? 4 : 5;
}
```